# How to match lines of text that start and end with specific characters?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which contains a list of items like below.

```
leptop
pencil
group
leptop
book
gruop
buk
grop
laftop
pensil
laptop
pancil
laptop bag
bok
```

From this, I want to design a regex pattern which will match lines that start with the letter "l" and end with "op".

This is what I tried:

```
a = re.search("^l.*op",line).group(0)
```

but I am getting:

```
leptop
leptop
laftop
laptop
laptop # this one I don't want because it's coming from the word "laptop bag"
```

Is there any way to get like below?

```
[leptop,leptop,laftop,laptop]
[pencil,pensil,pancil]
[group,gruop,grop]
[book,buk,bok]
[laptop bag]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need end of line anchor `$` for you regex:

```
import re
a = re.search("^l.*op$",line).group(0)
```

`op$` Matches `op` from the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a regex for this. `string.startswith` and `string.endswith` function will do this job.

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("l") and line.strip().endswith("op"):
            print(line, end="")' file
leptop
leptop
laftop
laptop
```